# Same WordPress under sub domain for mobile theme

Tags: wordpress, mobile

This is just a beginner question, but i'm stuck. The best option  i can find so far is using mobify and use their system then i change my subdomain cname to them.
But unfortunately mobify is not compatible with my data, since i have a small custom ecommerce site.
So what i want to do is redirecting my mobile visitors to subdomain for example: m.domain.com
i can make a plugin to check the visitors device and redirect them to subdomain.
My problem is, can i use the same WordPress (all posts and settings) at the subdomain (m.domain.com) and load the mobile theme?
If you experience any advice is greatly appreciate.
Thanks and Best regards
Ivan

Answer (score 0):

have you seen [this](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mobile-pack/) or [this](http://www.blogtips.org/how-to-enable-mobile-theme-on-wordpress-blog/) ?

Short version: just [install this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-mobile-detector/) :-)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks wezzy, yeah i got it working if it is on the same domain. But i'm stuck to move it to subdomain such as m.domain.com just to serve the mobile user. But still use the same data.